# grant permission on sharepoint site using CSOM without write user credentials in the code

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have written CSOM code to grant permission on share point sit but I put my credentials as hard code(my username,my password) in the code,how can I write my code with fixed them in the code
my code:

```
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://portal-staging/");
        ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        ctx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("my username", "my password");
        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("teeeest");
        var ListItem = list.GetItemById(2);
        RoleDefinitionBindingCollection rd = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);
        rd.Add(ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Read"));
        Principal user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("Domain Name\\user name");
        ListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
        ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(user, rd);
        ListItem.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, you can try to refer to the following code to grant permission using CSOM:

```
private static void GrantPermissionTo(params string[] accounts)  
    {  
        var DocumentLibName= "<YourDocumentLibraryName>"  
        context = new ClientContext(webUrl);  
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userId, FetchPasswordFromConsole());  
        Web web = context.Web;  
        context.Load(web);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();                 
         
        context.Load(web.Lists);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        context.Load(web.SiteUsers);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        context.Load(web.RoleDefinitions);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        context.Load(web.RoleAssignments);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
          
        var list = web.Lists.OfType<List>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Title.Equals(DocumentLibName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));  
        context.Load(list);              
        context.Load(list.RootFolder);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        context.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        
        var folderName = Path.GetFileName("<YourFolderName>");  
        var folder = list.RootFolder.Folders.OfType<Folder>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == folderName);  
        if (folder == null)  
            return;  
        context.Load(folder);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        context.Load(  
            folder,  
            fields => fields.ListItemAllFields,  
            fields => fields.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,  
            fields => fields.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
         
        if (!folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)  
        {  
            folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);  
            context.ExecuteQuery();  
        }  
         
        Array.ForEach(accounts, account =>  
        {  
            account =  account+"@"+<YourDomain>+".com";  
            try  
            {  
                RoleDefinition def;  
                //ForReadOnly  
                    def = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Read");  
                //ForContribute  
                    def = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Contribute");  
                RoleDefinitionBindingCollection rdb = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context);  
                rdb.Add(def);  
                Principal usr = context.Web.EnsureUser(account);                     
                folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(usr, rdb);  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                WriteLogMessage(ex.Message);  
            }  
        });  
        folder.Update();  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
    }
```

Also, we need to secured the password using SecureString, here is the code:

```
private static SecureString FetchPasswordFromConsole()  
   {  
       string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();  
       Console.WriteLine();  
       var securePassword = new SecureString();                
       foreach (char c in password)  
           securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
       securePassword.MakeReadOnly();  
       return securePassword;  
   }
```

**More information for reference:** [SharePoint Online - Grant And Remove Unique Permissions To Doc Library Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-online-grant-and-remove-unique-permissions-to-doc-library-using-csom)

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.